# Converting static HTML page (generated by BE from partial template files) to Angular (ngx)

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Situation is such - there is huge static html page generated with PHP framework and I need to migrate to angular (ngx or NOT 1.*).

The issue is that we need migrate components in the random order (sadly this condition can not change). So for example we can start with the part which sits in the top of the page, later migrate the footer...

With AngularJs (1.*) it would be simple as you just need to put `ng-app` attribute in the high level of html structure e.g. `<body ng-app>` and that's it - you are free to use directives/components all over the place inside it.

With Angular (ngx) it's different storry... You need to have root app component and rest of the html within it's scope (in other words convert everything tu ngx).

Is there any strategy which allows bootstrap multiple applications within same page? Or some other way which allows to use angular for the whole page and have parts of it as angular components parts of it still as static html generated by some BE templating system?